# ADB - how to check if file contains a string

Tags: android, macos, adb, zsh

I am trying to write a zsh script to check if a file contains specific string.

The difficulty I can't overcome is that the file is on Android device and I am executing the script on a Mac.

This is what I wrote (works if the file is on the Mac as well)

```
    if grep -q SpecificString "Desktop/file.json"
    then
    echo found
    else
    echo not found
    fi
```

Let's say that I want to check for SpecificString in a file on Android (storage/self/primary/file.json)

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible script might be the following:

```
#!/bin/zsh

adb shell grep "SpecificString" /sdcard/file.json
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "string found"
else
    echo "string not found"
fi
```

Of course you have to extend it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to copy the script to your Android device using `adb`. Then you can get a shell on the device with `adb shell` and run the script directly on the device.